# How to log executions of specific commands on Linux no matter where it came from?

Tags: linux, security, selinux

Dangerous commands like `rm` , `kill` and `systemctl stop`  can be hidden outside bash inputs - i.e. - a malicious user can easily hide them inside a python script using `os` module and just run the python script as a proxy to hide what they really intended to harm, and the bash history or anything like that will only leave the record that they run `python3 [the malicious script].py` before they delete that script to hide what they really did.

What I want to do is log those critical commands (any commands beyond the 3 is welcomed to point out) each time they got executed, no matter where it came from. And the log must not be disposable by any user except for root.

Comment: Sounds like you want to implement auditing in your system, [Configure Linux system auditing with auditd](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/configure-linux-auditing-auditd).

Comment: @U880D I tried auditd once and it occupies 80% of cpu. It was a disaster.

Comment: The `os` module doesn't run the `rm`, `kill`, etc. commands. They call directly the syscalls for the desired goal. E.g. to delete a file you use either the syscall `unlink` or `unlinkat`, and that's what `rm` calls as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `auditd` and monitor file operations/system calls to remove files/directories. The rules will be something like:

```
-a exit,always -S unlink -S rmdir -k Remove_dir_file
```

Of course you can add other calls of specific files monitoring in rules like for `kill`:

```
-a exit,always -F arch=b64 -S kill -k Kill_Process
```

Comment: Hi Romeo! I have also found that a simple copy of some command would also work i.e. `cp copy /usr/bin/rm ./` and `./rm` functions just like the orignal `rm`. Is there a mechanism to monitor `cp` and `mv` on these executable files?

Comment: @GeorgeY, yes, you can just add rule with proper system calls names after `-S`

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 : Find command location

```
which <command>
```

Step 2: Get acl by `getfacl <command path>`

Step 3: Use `setfacl` to set acl for allowed users

Setp 4: All permission issues logs will be available in audit logs in /var/log folder normally.

Hope this will help.

***Edit:***

***I was under impression that question is to handle commands via programme (not considered low level code).***

We can get all failed open call with below auditctl(If configured to monitor/logged)

```
To see unsuccessful open calls:
auditctl -a exit,always -S open -F success=0
```

So, sequence will be set the acls for files/commands and log the failed system calls via `auditd` so we can checkout logs. By this way we can get who tried to execute which command or syscall.

Note: I am not considering condition if programme is executed with root.

Comment: This really makes no sense in the context of the question as [python os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html) doesn't necessarily execute `command` by calling the `command` executable ; for example rather than calling `/usr/bin/kill` there is [`os.kill()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.kill) which implements sending signals to an application

Comment: My understanding was with question that he asked Linux commands execution via python.

Comment: @HBruijn `import os, kill   kill([PID], signal.SIGSTOP)` does not kill the process, especially when `kill` needs `sudo` privilege

Comment: @GeorgeY that doesn't change if you do `os.system("kill [PID]")`, though.

Comment: The OP's question seems to be based on a misunderstanding that the only way to emulate these commands in a program is with `os.system()`, not things like `os.kill()` and `os.unlink()`.

Comment: @Barmar : unless you are the root user, you cannot kill any program not started by yourself by simply using os.kill([pid]) or os.system('kill [pid]'), because you need a word `sudo` at the beginning.

Comment: @GeorgeY True, that's an exception.

Comment: @asktyagi I cannot find the log you suggested in `/var/log` and anything I found close to that is the `/var/log/audit/audit.log with words like `exe="/usr/sbin/sshd"`

Comment: @GeorgeY I updated my answer,  I think you can get what you want with `auditd` and `acls`. thanks to @Romeo for adding details about auditd.